# Resolve Library Conflict in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a Boolean or function to set "resolve library conflict" to automatically replace in Flash ActionScript3? I've searched addItem and Paste, but I'm still given the prompt.

Comment: i don't get your question, what kind of library conflict are you trying to solve? I don't think that there is any automatic way, besides, this would be silly

Comment: I guess he is after an option to turn off alert when copy paste items in FLA library and duplicates are found - it shouldn't be downvoted as it would be useful to know if it is possible.
@user1739337 - have you searched for JSFL solutions?